# Sourcing Dataframes and looping to create a list/dataframe

Tags: r, api, loops

I am trying to source data from Comtrade's API (https://comtrade.un.org/data) using R. I have the following function for sourcing data country by country which works fine:

```
(list <- get.Comtrade(r="842", p="826", ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS", cc="All"))
```

The r and p arguments are country codes. The output from the function above gives me a list. The data I need from this list can be located and saved to a df as follows: `df <- list[["data"]]`.

However, I need to loop over the p argument in the function above (while leaving the r argument fixed) to retrieve data for multiple countries and save this in a single df.

How could I do this without having to run the function country by country and then retrieving the data one by one?

so for example, say I need need the following p's: `p = c("826", "276")`, then to retrieve one country individually I would do `list_1 <- get.Comtrade(r="842, p="826",ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS", cc="All")`. Then to access the data and create a df I would do `df <- list_1[["data"]]`. Finally I would use `rbind()` to append the df of country "826" and the df of country "276".

This is what I need to run in a loop as I have a significant number of p's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its a function I created myself using this link https://comtrade.un.org/Data/Doc/api/ex/r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to pass multiple `p`s, use `lapply` to loop over

```
lapply(pvec, function(pv) get.Comtrade(r="842", p=pv, 
      ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS", cc="All")[["data"]])
```

If we get the same column names as output, the `list` output from `get.Comtrade` can be row binded with `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(pvec, function(pv) get.Comtrade(r="842", p=pv, 
      ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS", cc="All")[["data"]]))
```

---

In `tidyverse`, this can be done with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(pvec, ~ get.Comtrade(r = "842", p = .x,
             ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS",
          cc="All")[["data"]], .id = 'grp')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply akrun! the get.Comtrade command gives me a list for which to access the data I need to following command `df <- list[['data']]`. How can I loop over p and save the output of all these dataframes into a single dataframe though?

Comment: @Pythonista  DOes it have the same column names as output?

Comment: Yes, the output from `df <- list[['data']]` always has the same columns

Comment: @Pythonista  Can you check my update?  Do you also need any identifier column to specify from which 'p' value it is generated?

Comment: in principle no, if a single dataframe from the outputs is created, it would have a column for which it specifies which p country is used. However, what I do have is a df which has two columns, the first one with the name of the country and the second with its code. these are the countries I need in my output

Comment: Thank you so much for the help so far akrun!

Comment: @Pythonista  I added couple of methods.  Probably, would help

Comment: I will try them and post here if it solved the problem!

Comment: Just tried them, but unfortunately  they don't give me back what I need. So essentially, say I need need the following p's:

Comment: Just tried them, but unfortunately  they don't give me back what I need. So essentially, say I need need the following p's: `p = c("826", "276")`, then to retrieve in individually I would do `list_1 <- get.Comtrade(r="842, p="276",ps="201901", freq="M", fmt="csv", px = "HS", cc="All")`. Then to access the data and create a df I would do `df <- list_1[["data"]]`. Finally I would use `rbind()` to append all the different df's

Comment: @Pythonista  Okay, got it.  I think your function is returning multiple elements from which you are extracting only the "data", is that right?

Comment: Thanks so much for the code, I think this is almost what I need. However, I was wondering what pvec is? an empty list? As I am retrieving the data from the API, I do not have a list until its created with the function `get.Comtrade()`, so how would it work in this case? also I assume the `pv` argument is the same as the `p` array I have above, right?

Comment: @Pythonista  It is a vector of values `pvec <- c("826", "827", ...)`  Here, we loop over the vector with `lapply`, returning single value in each loop, ie.l the first list element would be `826` going  ionto the function, second one is '827', etc...